# Move a window to another Desktop

Tags: windows, windows-11-v22h2

How can I move a window (*that doesn't appear in Task View*) to another desktop?

**Please Note**: It does not appear in Task View.

Comment: If it does not appear in Task View, it's perhaps a dialog?

Comment: no it isn't .. it's a window that I can move around the screen... and it definitely isn't modal. It's just a kind of utility window for the program.. other more important window of the program do show up in task view. This window is just to run a compiler. The reason I want to move it to another desktop is that it is annoying to have to switch desktops every time I need to use it to unload the dlls, so I can then proceed to compile the dlls from the IDE which is on another desktop.

Comment: It seems to me easier to make a shortcut for it. That will be on any desktop. Just use it where you are.

Comment: well the shortcut will still switch me to the desktop. it is faster to just switch to the desktop (my mouse does that quickly).. and then I still have to switch back. It is annoying because I have to do it often. But I guess i need to find some kind of program that puts a menu item in the the top left corner menu of the window and lets me "move to desktop".. I had something like this before but it was windows 10.. this was great but the developer seemed to stop working on it with windows 10 https://github.com/Eun/MoveToDesktop .. and such programs won't work on win11 unless coded for it

Comment: This will not likely help but I use numerous apps and operating systems on my Windows 11 host and use windows (not full screen) and move around utterly seamlessly without opening or closing an app window

Comment: @John yes that doesn't help, this is specifically about windows of a program that **are not visible in Task View** so cannot be dragged in Task View to other desktops. There are many other windows in this application that can be dragged to other desktops, but the one I really need to move is problematic